# How to separate a executing path to file path and parameter?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

There are such lines as

```
C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\RAVCpl64.exe -s
```

in the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Now I want to separate the absolute path and parameters from the line.

If the line is

```
C:\Space Dir\Dot.Dir\Sample Name.Dot.exe param path."C:\Space Dir\Dot.Dir\Sample Name.Dot.exe"
```

Which separator should I use to deal with this line? Is there any Windows API function to solve this problem?

Comment: You could use the the *-* (dash) to tokenize your string?

Comment: @TonyTheLion but some application's parameter begins with other char

Comment: You mean you are trying to write code to parse the program and arguments from the command line?  This is not very straightforward as there are ambiguities in paths containing spaces.  Look at the documentation for [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically about the `lpApplicationName` parameter.  As far as I know there is no Windows API encapsulating that logic so you would have to write it yourself.

Comment: The first path isn't enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: @Jay The program is about to parse all the values in reg key  above.Enclosing with quotes actually makes parsing easier but I wonder if there is such unenclosed line in reg key.

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is in the standard C library that you can use in Windows.

```
char theDrive[5],thePath[MAX_PATH],theFilename[MAX_PATH],theExtension[MAX_PATH];

_splitpath(theSCTDataFilename,theDrive,thePath,theFilename,theExtension);
```

You can also use a more general tokenizing function like this which takes any string, a char and a CStringArray..

```
void tokenizeString(CString theString, TCHAR theToken, CStringArray *theParameters)
{
CString temp = "";
int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < theString.GetLength(); i++ ) 
    {                                   
    if (theString.GetAt(i) != theToken) 
       {
       temp += theString.GetAt(i);  
       }
     else
       {
       theParameters->Add(temp);    
       temp = "";
       }

         if(i == theString.GetLength()-1)
      theParameters->Add(temp);
    }
}

CStringArray thePathParts;
tokenizeString("your\complex\path\of\strings\separated\by\slashes",'/',&thePathParts);
```

This will give you an array of CString (CStringArray object) that contains each      section of the input string.  You can use this function to parse the major chunks then the minor ones as long as you know the seperator charactor you want to split the string on.